# How to configure Flask-Babel to work with blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app with many blueprints. Each blueprint is a python package. Now how can I have translations alongside each package?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

1. Put a `babel.cfg` file alongside `__init__.py` inside each package.
2. Create a directory, say `translations`, inside each package.
3. Follow [this instructions](https://python-babel.github.io/flask-babel/#translating-applications) to translate each package.
4. When you create your Flask app, find the absolute paths to each installed package by:

   ```
   import pkg_1
   import pkg_2
   abs_path_pkg_1 = os.path.dirname(sys.modules["pkg_1"].__file__)
   abs_path_pkg_2 = os.path.dirname(sys.modules["pkg_2"].__file__)
   ```
5. Append the `translations` folder to each path:

   ```
   abs_path_pkg_1 = abs_path_pkg_1 + "/translations"
   abs_path_pkg_2 = abs_path_pkg_2 + "/translations"
   ```
6. Create a semi-colon separated string of absolute paths to translation folders and then tell Flask-Babel where to look for translations:

   ```
   app.config["BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES"] = abs_path_pkg_1 + ";" + abs_path_pkg_2
   ```

I tested the above approach and it works. But I am not sure about the step 4. Is it the right way to access a folder inside an installed package?